# Remove text and tag in string

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a string like that

```
<span style="display:none">1597854383017</span>7 days ago
```

I want to remove all elements in even span tag.

I try with:

```
str = str.replace(/<\/?span[^>]*>/g,"");
console.dir(str);
```

result is

```
15978543830177 days ago
```

I want
7 days ago

Comment: Here's an alternative using `$("<div/>").html(text)`: https://jsfiddle.net/ba9v8x3u/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this:

```
<\/?span.*[^>]*>
```

result of https://regex101.com/:

[image]

Comment: Generally not a good idea to use regex for HTML processing: this will fail if you have more than one `<span>` https://regex101.com/r/KkFPIs/1/